# using deja dup with rsync server

Tags: rsync, duplicity, dejadup

I used Deja Dup on Ubuntu since years with an remote NFS share. Now I have a new home server, which also runs an rsync daemon. How can I connect deja Dup to this daemon instead of NFS?

I found out how to connect duplicity from the command line of the client to the remote rsync daemon:

```
duplicity --no-encryption testfile.txt rsync://server::module/backupfolder/
```

This works fine, the client gives out plausible Backup Statistics, no errors and the backup arrives on the server, so I consider my rsync server running and configured correctly and reachable by the client.

But when I put `rsync://server::module/backupfolder/` into the client's Deja Dup settings as backup location, it says after starting a backup "location cannot be mounted" or similar.
Is the URL syntax wrong?
What else am I doing wrong? Isn't Deja Dup supposed to work the same way as duplicity, since it uses duplicity?

*edit: I corrected the paths, but still no luck connecting with deja dup

Answer (score 0):

According to https://answers.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+question/143517 the duplicity functionality is not exposed by Deja Dup, it's not implemented.